# "From all different" or "from all the different" ...?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm not sure which is correct. For example:

> "Students from all the different schools of the college..."

vs.

> "Students from all different schools of the college..."

Comment: As the schools are (post-)identified (of the college), the inclusion of the  definite article is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it without "the different".
**"Students from all schools of the college..."**

And everyone will know you mean various or more than one.